# Should foreign personal titles be capitalized in English text?

Tags: fiction, novel

Should foreign language personal titles be capitalized in English fiction text?

E.g. "How are you, Señor Rojas?"

Do we follow English language rules for capitalization?

In Spanish it would read:
Cómo está señor Rojas?

Answer (score 2):

All honorifics or personal titles are capitalized in English as part of the name, whether they are "foreign" or not:

How are you, Mr. Johnson?

Look, here comes Colonel Mustard!

Her marriage is so tragic, she reminds me of Madame Bovary.

He bears a striking resemblance to Czar Nikolas.

In Spanish "señor" is not capitalized, but the style of the vast majority of publications is to capitalize it when used in an English work.

Note that none of those titles would be capitalized if they were not a title immediately before a name: the country was ruled by a czar; she was a madame; he reached the rank of colonel; and so on.